# changing a PHP $SESSION value by clicking on a div

Tags: php, onclick, session-variables

I'm trying to change the value of a PHP session variable when the user clicks on a `div` element.

There are several div elements on the page and each will change the session variable to a different value.

At the moment I have the following code under the first div as a test but can't get it to change the variable's value.

```
<div class="workpiece" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['pageRef'] = 1; ?>">
```

I would greatly appreciate any  help as I'm very new to this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MVC architecture or core PHP?

Comment: I'm currently using core PHP

Comment: Please try to implement it with ajax requests as mentioned in following answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting server side code in client side script. You cannot do this, as server side code executes before it is sent to the browser. What you can do, is send an ajax request to a PHP script on click.

```
<script>
function sendajax() {
    $.post('scriptforsession.php', {}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
</script>

onclick='sendajax();'
```

Comment: so I will need a separate php page that will change the $_SESSION value? and should the onclick be: onclick='sendajax(1);'   ?

Comment: Or a page and then in the data part of the post request put this: {action: "pageRef"}. Then you can have a multipurpose script that executes code by $_POST ['action'].

Comment: @user3340589 - why would you need to pass the integer 1 to the sendajax function?

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. Managed to achieve what I wanted to do  by using your code as a starting point and experimenting somewhat.

Comment: @user3340589 - No problem what so ever, I am glad you achieved your goal! If you have any other questions, let me know and I'll try to be of assistance. Would you mind marking the answer as correct, though?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax would be one solution but I think what you are trying could also be handled by simply putting the page reference in a GET. Though this will make the page reload. Then in your PHP simple use the $_GET['pageRef']

```
<div class="workpiece" onclick="window.location='?pageRef=1';">
```